# java script for radiobuttonlist select and deselect

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a radio buttonlist control. in which data are coming from DB and  binding in a .cs  file

now I need to write a javascript that if user select item 1 in radiobuttonlist it gets selected and again user clicks on the same item it should get deselected.

even if I have 10  items under it  this  thing should open
 that select and  deselect the item clicking on it

thank you

Comment: Radio buttons are usually used if you require someone to make at least one choice eg; Male / Female. If you want select / deselect, eg; select / deselect, why not use a tickbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" onclick="Toggle(this);">

var radios = new Array;
function Toggle(radio) 
{
    if (radios[radio.name] == radio.value) 
    {
        radio.checked = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        radio.checked = true;
        radios[radio.name] = radio.value;
    }
}
```